# close and open button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want single button to `open` and `close`.

This is what I'm using for my side menu to `close and open`:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

and this is the button open

```
<span class="collapses" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;float:right;color:
#fff;margin-top: 20px" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

and this is the button to close

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
```

Comment: You don't have question, do you?

Comment: i just mention above

Comment: If you just want to hide and show the button, better to use the `display` or the `visibility` CSS property in case you need to keep the layout occupied by the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```js
function openNav() {
  if (document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width != "300px") {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="collapses" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;float:right;color:
red;margin-top: 20px" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; CLICK</span>

<div id="mySidenav" style="background-color:blue;width:300px">
  <p>Some content.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Toggle the width based on current width value using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
function openNav() {
  var div = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
  div.style.width = div.style.width != '300px' ? "300px" : 0;
}
```

Comment: this works fine but for the first time i have to click twice to open the side menu if i refresh my page then i have to press twice can u help

Answer (score 0):

> Without jQuery and any changes you want to make

You might wrap the `openNav`and `closeNav` calls into a third function that manages the open/close state.

```
function openNav(){...}
function closeNav(){...}

var isOpen = false;

function toggleNav(){
   if(isOpen) {
     closeNav();
     isOpen = false;
   }else{
     openNav();
     isOpen = true;
   }
}
```

Then just call `toggleNav()` on button click.

This lets you use any configuaration of style changes without using jQuery or checking for previous values.